# Enter fastboot commands from an Android phone

Tags: hardware, fastboot

I want to do the following without a PC, just directly from an Android phone using a script / Android Terminal:

> Reboot into bootloader, and then enter a few fastboot commands

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, thats not possible -- as there is no UI (including terminal) available in fastboot mode.